# como dar estilo a la seleccion de una tabla?

Tags: css3, bootstrap-4, tablas, bootstrap

Tengo que maquetar una web que tiene la tabla de la foto, estoy usando bootstrap y ya logre redondear los bordes, pero no encuentro nada sobre como editar las celdas cuando son seleccionadas... tampoco manejo mucho js... y no se como deberia realizarse ese comportamiento. Podrian orientarme un poco (para saber al menos que debo buscar para conseguir maquetar los contornos azules) despues los dev van a hacer la magia, peor no se ni por donde comienza el truco jajaja. Mil gracias por rescatarme de este callejón sin salida.

Dejo abajo el codigo que tengo hasta el momento (es una tabal basica de bootstrap con borde redondeado)

[image: como debe quedar la tabla]

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.table tr td,
.table tr th {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.table thead tr th:first-child {
  border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.table thead tr th:last-child {
  border-radius: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
}

.table tbody tr:last-child th:first-child {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 8px;
}

.table tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered r">
  <thead>
    <tr class="">
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

intente darle border-left, pero se qeuda dentro de la tabla, no fuera
[image: intento de border]

Comment: Yo usaría una clase de **CSS** para darle ese aspecto de seleccionado con los bordes azules que quieres darle.Esto es muy cómodo para los desarrolladores ya que así lo único que tienen que hacer es quitarla o ponerla a través de **JS** cuando lo consideren nececesario.

Comment: normalmente lo realizaria asi, el problema es que no se que editar en el css para que se salga de la tabla la pestaña azul... probe padding en la primer fila y nada

Comment: ¿Sinceramente? Hacerlo con una `<table>` te va a dificultar mucho la labor. Yo lo haría con `<div>`. Tendría tres columnas por fila, siendo la primera la pestaña, dejándola oculta y mostrándola solamente cuando la fila se encuentre seleccionada..

Comment: lo pense... porque me esta rompiendo la cabeza, pero no se si despues puede dificultar que agreguen o modifiquen la tabla los usuarios? tenes idea de eso? para no complicarle la vida al programador despues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe un framework llamado JExcel que hace exactamente eso que pides:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jexcel/2.1.0/js/jquery.jexcel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jexcel/2.1.0/css/jquery.jexcel.min.css">

<div id="table"></div>

<script>
data = [
  ['#', 'Handle'],
  [2, '@fat']
];

$('#table').jexcel({
  data:data, colWidths: [ 200, 200, 200 ]
})
</script>
```

Puedes encontrar más información [aquí](https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v4/).

Answer (score 2):

Si dices que las celdas de las tablas van a ser editables por los usuarios, existe algo en **Bootstrap** que se asemeja mucho a lo que necesitas. Los `.input-group`.

Usando estos podrías hacer que la pestaña que tienen con `.input-group-prepend` esté oculta hasta el momento que lo necesites.

Monté un ejemplo rápido para que lo veas. Haciendo **click** en una de las filas provocarías que apareciera la pestaña.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.input-group').click(function () {
    let elemento = $(this);
    
    $('.input-group').removeClass('seleccionada');
    elemento.addClass('seleccionada');
  });
});
```

```css
.input-group-prepend {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.seleccionada .input-group-text {
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.seleccionada .form-control:focus {
  border-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0rem rgba(0,123,255,.25);
}

.seleccionada .input-group-prepend {
  visibility: visible;
}

.seleccionada .form-control {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: muero de la emosión.... mil gracias por interesarte en solucionarlo

Comment: se puede con js cambiar el input group a las columnas?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres?

Comment: porqeu necesito que la seleccion se realice en las filas o en las columnas (segun quiera el usuario) sino me parece que va a ser mejor con los divs...